# PyQt5 how to display seconds on QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using A QTableWidget to display some data.

The problem is that my first column is a QDateTime and the QTableWidget doesn't display the seconds. 
I tried to change QDateTime to QTime and it doesn't show the second too.

And when i try to sort them it's not correct ( i guess it come from the first problem, it will maybe be a next question )

I didn't found any solution in the Qt documentation.

```
            self.widgetEvents = QtGui.QTableWidget(numberOfEvents, 4);
        self.widgetEvents.keyPressEvent = self.keyPressOnWidgetEvent;
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoMousePropagation);
        self.widgetEvents.contextMenuEvent = self.contextMenuEvent;

        self.widgetEvents.hide();
        self.rightPanelUi.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widgetEvents)

        customHeader = HeaderTableView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self.widgetEvents)
        customHeader.setStretchLastSection(True)
        customHeader.setHighlightSections(True)
        customHeader.setSectionsClickable(True)
        #customHeader.setSortIndicatorShown(True)

        customHeader.setContextMenuTreeWidgetCallBack(self.getDataToShowAvaillableFilters)

        customHeader.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        customHeader.customContextMenuRequested.connect(customHeader.showContextMenu)

        self.widgetEvents.setHorizontalHeader(customHeader)

        self.widgetEvents.setHorizontalHeaderLabels((_('Date'), _('Category'), _('Type'), _('Description')))

        #self.widgetEvents.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(self.sortData)
        self.widgetEvents.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.widgetEvents.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.widgetEvents.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.widgetEvents.setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: rgb(240,240,240); background-color: white;")
        self.widgetEvents.setShowGrid(False)
        self.widgetEvents.hide();

        k = 0; # date & hour
        for e in eventsLogFramesDecoded:
            itemDateTime = QTableWidgetItem()
            #strdatetime = str(e[6]) + '/' + str(e[5]) + '/' + str(2000 + int(e[4])) + ' ' +  str(e[7]) + ':' + str(e[8]) + ':' + str(e[9]);

            date = QDate(2000 + int(e[4]) ,int(e[5]), int(e[6]) )
            time = QTime(int(e[7]), int(e[8]), int(e[9]))
            #dateTime = QDateTime(date, time)
            #dateTime = QDateTime(date, time, 1)

            #itemDateTime.setData(0,strdatetime);
            #itemDateTime.setData(0,  QDateTime(date, time, 1));
            itemDateTime.setData(0, time);
            print(str(time))

            self.widgetEvents.setItem(k, 0, itemDateTime);
            k = k + 1;
```

Thank !

Comment: I would suggest you to change `itemDateTime.setData( 0, time )` to `itemDateTime.setData( 0, time.toString( "hh:mm:ss AP" ) )`. It makes more sense to me to set the DisplayRole to a `string` rather than a `QTime` object

Comment: i could do it but to sort them, i will have to convert each str to QDate and QTime then QDateTime, it can be a little heavy no ? I mean setData should accept Qt type else i should use setText() no ?

Comment: My problem is with `setData( 0, ... )`. It is not the question what `setData` accepts. You see `0` or rather `Qt.DisplayRole` is reserved for the text that your view will display. So if you put a `QTime` object, then, Qt will in its way interpret the time in `QString` as use it, leading to loss of data, the way you have experienced. So It would be nice to put a `str` or `QString` there. If you want to store `QTime` in your `QTableWidgetItem` feel free to use `setData( Qt.UserRole + 1, ... )` and so forth. As for conversion you could use `QDateTime.fromString` directly.

Comment: As for being heavy, I doubt very much if it will be very heavy. Unless of course, if you have thousands of cells to fill. You can create a `QDateTime` directly as `dt = QDateTime( QDate( 2000 + e[4], e[5], e[6] ), QTime( e[7], e[8], e[9] ) )` Then display the date time in the item as `itemDateTime.setData( 0, dt.toString( "MMM dd, yyyy  hh:mm:ss AP" ) )` and `itemDateTime.setData( Qt.UserRole + 1, dt )` If you have a large amount of data, it would be much more efficient to use one of the item models  that suit you or subclass `QAbstractItemModel` with a subclass of `QTableView`

Comment: Yes, i will do it that way for the moment thank !